# React Native: How to create text with fixed character widths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a timer, but the width of the text changes depending on the numbers.  letterSpacing doesn't seem to work. If I set the textAlign to left, it fixes the problem slightly, but that's only because the hour numbers rarely change compared to the seconds and milliseconds, so that solution is not ideal.

[image]

Comment: Since we are making text center, that's behavior is expected. What about fixed width(count the last digit always)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using the default font -San Francisco- which supports a font feature of monospaced digits, here is how to use it:

```html
// fontVariant must be an array of strings
{fontVariant: ['tabular-nums']}
```

For more information regarding other font variants that you can use [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props.html#fontvariant).

Answer (score -2):

Try using a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

In react native try setting `{fontFamily: 'monospace'}` and then pick a monospaced font you like.

Comment: there is no such family called 'monospace', fontFamily will not enable the monospaced digits, which is what needed